# Run time error using cv::imwrite in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using OpenCV 2.3.1.  My language is C++.

cv::imwrite works fine if I hard code the name of the output file like this.

```
cv::imwrite("/home/peter/BlendedInterpolatedPlane.jpg", srcnorm);
```

However, I get a run time error when I try to pass the output file name as a string like this.

```
cv::imwrite(outputFileName.c_str(), srcnorm);
```

or like this

```
cv::imwrite(outputFileName, srcnorm);
```

although there is no compiler error.

outputFileName is declared as std::string and contains the output file name.

The stack trace is as follows.

```
org.netbeans.modules.viewmodel.TreeModelNode@1999add[Name=, displayName=__kernel_vsyscall()]    
org.netbeans.modules.viewmodel.TreeModelNode@186304c[Name=, displayName=raise()]    
org.netbeans.modules.viewmodel.TreeModelNode@cce801[Name=, displayName=abort()] 
org.netbeans.modules.viewmodel.TreeModelNode@93b1a8[Name=, displayName=__gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler()()]  
org.netbeans.modules.viewmodel.TreeModelNode@749412[Name=, displayName=Address: [@0x00554fa5]]  
org.netbeans.modules.viewmodel.TreeModelNode@1a52b00[Name=, displayName=std::terminate()()] 
org.netbeans.modules.viewmodel.TreeModelNode@aa277d[Name=, displayName=__cxa_throw()]   
org.netbeans.modules.viewmodel.TreeModelNode@106904c[Name=, displayName=cv::error(cv::Exception const&)()]  
org.netbeans.modules.viewmodel.TreeModelNode@1eb6f21[Name=, displayName=cv::imwrite_(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,   std::allocator<char> > const&, cv::Mat const&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&, bool)()]   
org.netbeans.modules.viewmodel.TreeModelNode@1ccf1f3[Name=, displayName=cv::imwrite(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, cv::_InputArray const&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)()]    
org.netbeans.modules.viewmodel.TreeModelNode@20a41d[Name=, displayName=main(argc=9,argv=0xbffff564) at main.cpp:259]
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated,
Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.  The output file name had an invalid suffix.  Once I fixed that problem, it worked with

```
cv::imwrite(outputFileName, srcnorm);
```

where outputFileName is of type std::string.